# How sockets determine the requesting machine

Tags: sockets, websocket

how does a socket finds my private ip address as public ip are different than private and inside a public network there can be many private ip addresses with listening to a particular port

Comment: Every IP packet you send contains your source address.

Comment: I am talking about response from some server ....
how does it identifies my machine ?
means how will it know my private ip , because it will send the packet to my public ip.

Comment: Because of NAT/PAT. Your router changes the packets and remembers which internal IP belongs to a certain connection.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks a lot for that easy explanation. If you have some links for that topic ,give me.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a remote machine to send packets to your computer, the remote machine must know it's "public" (from the view of the remote machine) IP address.

Most routers these days have only a single IP address assigned to them from the upstream service and so do [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT) for those machines behind it.

Every IP packet outbound from your machine to an outside server has it's address changed to the public address of the router and the router keeps an internal record with the destination address & port along with the true source that sent it.  Every inbound packet has the originating address & port checked against those records to find out what internal machine should receive it; the destination address is set appropriately and the packet forwarded.

Neither side can generally tell (or care) that NAT is happening.

Note, however, that you can't initiate a connection from the outside to an internal machine because there is no record indicating where those initial packets should be sent; additional static configuration would be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant explanation

Comment: An upvote and "accepted" answer is the typical way of saying "thanks".